# SCM: Load from a load rule file

Tags: rational-team-concert

In SCM, there are different ways to load a components but I am bit confused with the "Load from a load rule file" option https://jazz.net/library/article/1016 I gone through this link and got to know how to load the loadrule file using "Load from a load rule file" option. Can anyone give me a brief note on "Load from a load rule file" and in what circumstances this option will give hand?

Answer (score 1):

You have a good illustration of potential use cases in "[Loading with Load Rules in Rational Team Concert 4.0 and later](https://jazz.net/library/article/1015)"

> Load rules are a way of describing what is loaded from a repository workspace and where it should be loaded.
>
> It could take several steps to load a repository workspace exactly as you would like in the sandbox and to repeat those steps can be error prone for yourself and other team members.
> However, if the layout information is captured in load rules, they can be easily re-used by other team members when loading their repository workspace into their sandbox.
> They can also be used in builds.

Another use case ([in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/131349/how-to-maintain-folder-structure-while-selectively-loading-folders-within-scm-component-in-rtc)): "How to maintain folder structure while selectively loading folders within SCM Component in RTC"

> Once that is all done, you can capture 'how' you loaded everything in a load rule file so that in the future you can simply load from a load rule file instead of re-doing the steps above.
> Navigate to `"Window" --> "Preferences" --> "Team " --> "Jazz Source Control" --> "Sandboxes"`. Click on the sandbox that represents your eclipse workspace (or which ever sandbox you just loaded everything into) and select the `"Generate Load Rules..."`. In the dialog you can choose where you want to save the load rule file and click `"Generate"`.